# Is possible to use third-party .dll (.Net Framework 2.0) with ASP.Net Core 2.0 project?

Tags: c#, dll, .net-2.0, compatibility, asp.net-core-2.0

Is possible to use third-party .dll (.Net Framework 2.0) with ASP.Net Core 2.0 project?

I have a industrial device with API (Framework 2.0). I need to get some data form this device and put it on the nice-looking webside, so I decided use Angular 4 template with .Net Core 2.0.